# Who else wants the old navigation layout back?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, top-bar

Upvote if you want the old layout back, downvote if you like the new one. :D

Comment: I would like a userscript for the old one if available!

Comment: the dropdown is good. But, its damn pitch black. can't see a damn thing.

Comment: Man I should've changed the question to "upvote if you like the new one. Downvote, to have the old back." :(

Comment: This is not even a question. At least post something like "The old navbar should be restored because of these rational and well-thought out reasons: ..." and let the up/downvotes come naturally.

Comment: Agree with @Juhana here. The top bar navigation wasn't thrown together overnight. If you have an issue with the new and updated functionality, state that.

Answer (score 8):

### [Userscript](https://github.com/travisjj/SE-LightSide)

### meta preview

[image: meta]

### so preview

[image: so]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately you've only brought back the old style (which I don't care about), not the old functionality apart from the main/meta link. (Wide inbox button at the left instead of that tiny square bra icon, and the number of votes cast today (and other useful info) when hovering on the user name.)

Comment: @Gilles - I had only assumed styles :) Re-implementing a hover over the name for the popout would be nice, but I have a feeling that the server side functionality which was being ajax'd to is probably removed in the current build - or at least will be soon.

Comment: @Gilles - The userscript now contains the username hover box.

Comment: Very nice, does this work in a similar way on firefox?

Comment: @span - I have not worked with making firefox addons so I am not sure you would get as much out of it as the userscript in chrome gives. There is no reason why this will not work in firefox though.

Comment: [I do expect a percentage of all the money you make off of this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210016/161198) @TravisJ.

Comment: @Bart - Hahah, duly noted :D