# Would it be possible to lighten the color of the new top bar?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, top-bar, feedback

The new top bar layout is fine, but the black color is very visually jarring/intrusive.  Is using a lighter color an available option?

Comment: userscript it...

Comment: That could be the answer to all [top-bar] questions.

Comment: It was tempting @TheGrinch.

Comment: I have a userscript under development that's intended to make these userscripts easier.

Comment: A metascript?...

Comment: I agree with the lightening the color of the top bar... even something like `#404040` would be great... the black is way too intrusive.

Comment: @TheGrinch It's a userscript that supports userscript plugins. (Gee, can I call it a metascript?)

Comment: My approach: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210013/184087

Comment: I've now posted [Gallery of custom styles and/or scripts for the top-bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210041/gallery-of-custom-styles-and-or-scripts-for-the-top-bar) where hopefully other useful approaches will be posted.

Comment: https://github.com/imom0/so-topbar-light-theme try this for chrome users.

Comment: +1000. User preferences should offer at least some basic color/theme customization.

Comment: User preferences are a crutch for bad design.  The only excuse for the horrible palette is that it's the only one that "matches" all 106 SE sites.  That's a pretty thin excuse - it matches almost all of them equally poorly and makes them all look like they were designed by a chimp.  Designers could make a case study of this mess as an example of when you need to reconsider the problem being solved.  Bulldozing over a hundred sites, most with very carefully chosen colour schemes, is just a lazy solution.  Branding professionals exist.  Designers exist. SE needs to start consulting some of them.

Comment: Press down arrow. Voila, top bar out of sight out of mind.

Comment: It's a little lighter black now...

Comment: Black is the only neutral color matching all sites? Ha! White isn't neutral anymore? And the remaining 254 shades of gray? Follow [phils' link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210041/192154) to be proven wrong. Several UserStyles available with nice gray tones. Much more eye-friendly. And better fitting to all SE sites I tried.

Comment: 69 =) hope it make you smile (I know not a useful contribution but hey once in a while you just have to smile and share)

Comment: @CodeBlend  It does!  Thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It fits well on some sites. On most sites, it's indeed jarring. Beta sites, for example — all light blue/cyan/gray colors except for that black* band.

The color of the top bar should be adjusted for each site, to fit the site's theme.

*  <sub>Yeah, I know, not black.</sub>

Comment: It's not the color* that I find unappealing, it's the contrast.  A dark-anycolor band against a light page is distracting.

Comment: @JS. Someone understands. I visited SO earlier today, first time with new bar (have been on Meta for a few weeks, so saw the redesign), and I said wow, this is ugly and distracting.

Comment: @JS. Yes, I meant color as in the whole shebang, not just the hue.

Comment: @hichris123: Yeah, today is the first I've seen it too.  Been on Stack Exchange all week.  Looking through Meta's posts on the changes, these changes have been rolling out for a while.  Guess they just finally trickled into my corner of the Internet.

Comment: @Gilles: I understand.  I just wanted to clarify my position as Bart was teasing me about pink earlier.  :-)

Comment: The blog post says that one of the goals in the new top bar design was to provide a uniform look across all the sites, and that black is really the only option. I wonder if the team would consider at least creating a light color scheme to go with the current dark color scheme, for sites where the light scheme fits better?

Comment: It's a network feature, so I actually prefer the uniformly "black" thing.

Answer (score 20):

Make it transparent (suggestion originally from [Sci-Fi meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3232/new-topbar-clashes-with-scifi-se)):

[image: Transparent top bar from Sci-Fi]

Comment: While this looks great on sci-fi, and probably other sites with dark backgrounds, it wouldn't work on light-backgrounded sites. The foreground text color would have almost no contrast with the background color.

Comment: @BenLee We [just got a post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3238) that it'll use a darker 80% solid instead of my proposed 40% solid, which should work well on both dark and light sites.  Not sure if Jin meant just SciFi.SE+Meta or everywhere, though.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, this is not an available option.

But, as a workaround, [userscripting should get you pretty far](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209980/161198). Then you can have all the color-goodness you like. And let's be honest here, you really want it to be pink.

Comment: Hey, I'm secure in my programmer-hood. :-) Pink works so long as it lowers the contrast.  <sigh>  Guess I'll have to allocate some time to learn userscripting.