# Top bar with double color?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

Top bar showing double color for [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) for both main site and meta site.

AFAIK the color for top bar is #212121 as mentioned in the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/?cb=1). Check out the below screenshot. I can see this in opera and firefox on windows 7. It looks not nice on profile picture area.

> [image: normal screen]

With background set to be 100% transparent, it looks like this:

[image: 100% transparent screen]

The dark blue ends abruptly, creating double-colour effect after adding black semitransparent overlay.

Comment: It was `#212121` yesterday. I like the idea of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)` - it should generate "almost black" tinted with the colour of a site. I just think that other parts of the themes should be fixed to really make it work.

Comment: I edited in a second screenshot, interpreting OPs comment at Meta Drupal Answers as invitation to cooperate.

Comment: @Mołot thanks for joining and pointed out the exact appearance!

Comment: Same issue on the [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. It will go alive after the next production build.

Answer (score 6):

This actually appears to affect all SE sites which had a custom top-bar previously.

They're using a `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)` to generate the "blackish" color for the top-bar. For a site like Stack Overflow, this is not a problem because the background behind it is white. However, on a site like Drupal, the background behind that is a [header background image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/drupal/img/bg-top-bar.png), which has a built-in background-color for the top-bar that starts to bleed through the 80% transparent black that's being used on top of it.

For example, I can also reproduce this on English SE:

[image: Weird color bleeding]

Comment: Ok, but I can not see any official post, If you check the blog I linked you can see the A Bigger, Blacker Bar

Comment: It's an oversight. I doubt they tested this on other themes. They'd need to make it a solid color or fix the background images so they don't do that anymore.

Comment: @Bala only conversation with ♦ even remotely about this I recall was [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210102/new-top-bar-allow-user-colour-choices/210121?noredirect=1#comment673456_210121) and further discussion. I mean, it looks like an amazing coincidence I ask about something yesterday in comments and it is implemented (with little bug, but anyway) today.

Comment: FWIW: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3232/new-topbar-clashes-with-scifi-se