# Will I notified, when some one made an edit to my post?

Tags: support, tags, edits, notifications

My [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210346/top-bar-with-double-color) is edited for [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag, but I'm not notified for that edit, is this correct behaviour, AFAIK it will be intimated when the site without new top bar.

Comment: By design, just consider this a pleasant surprise. By the way usually the dev who fix/decline the bug will also post answer on which you do get notification. :)