# Is there an option to turn off the Community Bulletin? (Or, could it be added?)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, community-bulletin

For me this area, red box:

[image]

is completely annoying and pointless.

Is there an option to turn it off?

If not, should you dudes add such an option?

Note -

- **I'm not, in any way, opposed to SO monetizing.**
- Actually if that was *an ad* it would be less annoying, strangely enough.
- A great way to think about the huge mistake made here in your business model: that square indicated in red is *exactly* an example of the sort of crap that Google know to never, ever - ever - put on their product.

(Imagine if google Drive, say, or any of their products had a pointless box at the top with links to "blog!!! articles!" by vice presidents. It's not even funny - it's like a parody of adding pointless crap to a web product.)

Comment: What does monetising have to do with anything? The majority of what appears in that box are meta posts

Comment: ? would be like asking "When NBC runs a promo for their own shows rather than a Coke ad, how is that monetizing?"

Comment: Heh - the voting here really emphasizes the difference between "people who hang out on the meta site" and "working engineers who use SO to ask questions" !

Comment: You missed my point. That box *isn’t* full of promo or ads, it’s full of *meta posts* (i.e stuff the community is discussing amongst itself; nothing to do with the company)

Comment: ? "meta" is a marketing effort.  like adding "a logo", "tv ads" or "a! blog!"  (note that anyway, the first link is to a marketing! blog!)

Comment: Sure, there are blog posts, but not always and the majority aren’t. As for meta being a marketing effort... I don’t really understand what you’re saying (how do you equate a place where the community discusses itself with “tv ads”?)

Comment: You're right, google does sooooooo much better and would never waste quarter of the screen with useless "hints": https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOx22.png

Comment: ? that's a one-time popup.  **So, let's change the area in question on SO to a one-time popup**.  And indeed, everyone **loathes** those things they are experimenting with on Sheets.

Answer (score 10):

#### Is there an option to turn it off?

There is a userscript:

> SOX v2.1.0
>
> Stack Overflow Extras (SOX) is a project that stemmed from the Stack
> Overflow Optional Features (SOOF) project.
>
> The SOX userscript adds a bunch of optional features to all sites in
> the Stack Exchange network. These can be toggled on or off from an
> easy to use control panel (see screenshot below).
>
> Note: This project has no relation to Stack Overflow or Stack
> Exchange; it is simply a userscript that enhances the sites!

Source [sox/README.md at master · soscripted/sox](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/blob/master/README.md)

Example configuration:

> [image]

Comment: Fascinating info, thanks.  You know, I think it would be better if they just got rid of it as a native change though.  It would seem completely harmless to SO to add an option to remove it.

Comment: @Fattie A feature request like this would be way down the list of developer priorities.

Comment: If that's true, thanks for the info.  I mean - it's their business - but we're talking about the **second most prominent thing** on the actual product of SO.  The idea of google or amazon putting a "low priority" on such a hugely prominent Thing - is inconceivable.

Comment: @Fattie _"The idea of google or amazon putting a "low priority" on such a hugely prominent Thing"_ Well, they have a different business model. What else would you consider to make it driven in a better way?

Comment: @Fattie [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210121/) is an indication that a cosmetic feature like this that can already be enabled with user-script is unlikely to be implemented.

Comment: @Discretelizard - if (that's if) SO staff think "the layout of the main money making web page" is a "cosmetic issue" - they have no staff who have ever worked at amazon, google, or, uh, any web company.  Goodness!

Comment: "It's a very popular thing to block" I see, @user1114, interesting info

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Adblock Plus compatible ad blocker (I have uBlock Origin), it's as simple as adding the following filter rule:

```
##div[data-tracker="cb=1"]
```

If you have an extension for stylesheets (I have Stylus), you can add an entry like this

```
div[data-tracker="cb=1"] { display: none; }
```

to hide the Community Bulletin.