# Can we disable the new Stack Exchange look?

Tags: support, top-bar

The new top bar for Stack Exchange sites is unappealing to me. Is there a way to restore the old look?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210041/gallery-of-custom-styles-and-or-scripts-for-the-top-bar/210045#210045).. you can use a userscript.

Comment: No, not officially or entirely.

Comment: Seriously, people: why are you so massively downvoting a perfectly polite support request? (If the answer is “this isn't the first asker wanting this”, where are the duplicate close votes?)

Comment: @Gilles I would assume that you've learned, after so much participation in Meta, that downvotes are not related to how polite a request is, but rather simply whether I agree with it or not. I don't agree, so I downvoted. Not personal.

Comment: @Chris That's for discussions or feature requests. A support request isn't something you can disagree with. You can find it incomprehensible, or so easy to answer that the asker hasn't done research, etc., but how do you disagree with “how do I do this?”?

Comment: Do you have a document that outlines which posts on Meta are supposed to be voted on in what fashion? Some rubric to decide when a downvote is not appropriate? I suspect, and this is only a theory, that you do not because it doesn't exist. Just sayin' -- downvotes on meta are not personal.