# Where can I find meta activity stats now?

Tags: support, recent-activity, per-site-meta

Previously, bringing up the activity drop down (hovering over your username) used to bring up activity statistics on individual site metas, specifically including information on the number of upvotes/downvotes your meta posts had received during that day/week/month:

[image]

The page that was actually fetched when bringing up the drop down is still available for now at `individual-site.stackexchange.com/users/profile-link-stats` but accessing this to find out how many votes have been made against you for a period is a bit of a kludge.

Since the roll out of the new top bar, there is no activity drop down anymore, and there is no "reputation" section on individual site metas, where can I find meta activity stats now?

Comment: Information on the number of votes made against you does not exist on the profile page

Comment: You can use a userscript from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210041/gallery-of-custom-styles-and-or-scripts-for-the-top-bar if you want it back, but that will probably only work temporarily.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167648/162102

Comment: @MonicaCellio interesting, that information was previously available before the top bar change!

Comment: The *count* was available (in the username hover); that was a fairly recent change I think (last several months).  But the *specific posts with vote changes* weren't available; you got a "+4/-1 for the day" indicator but if you cared you had to look at your posts to try to spot the change.  I want the reputation-style list so it's easier to notice voting activity on old meta posts.

Comment: Ah yeah now I understand