# Will the color change in the upper bar be available tomorrow and beyond?

Tags: feature-request, april-fools, unicorns

It's the unicorn attack!

I bought the bar color change with my hard-earned Unicoins.

Even if the change is barely noticeable, I think it would be great to be able to change it, maybe even have more options.

So, I was wondering if this change will be available from now on, or if it's just for today...

Comment: Oh, it'll definitely be here tomorrow!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why you would think this feature is specific today. Unicoins are here to stay and are a viable option to bitcoins or litecoins.

Soon they will trend with the ebb and flow of the market all based on the color changing, vote hiding, unicorn animating powerhouse that this new feature has enabled.

Make no mistake, the US-BCN, US dollar to Bacon exchange rate, is going to skyrocket from this!

As a side note, you could always [userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210045/178816) it.

Comment: Is it really? I didn't actually know about userscript options, and I want 'em colors...