# "Top bar color chooser" power-up doesn't work for me

Tags: bug, april-fools, unicoins

I was happy when SE offers to [change the top bar color](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210012/would-it-be-possible-to-lighten-the-color-of-the-new-top-bar) for 80 Unicoins. However, when I tried it out, I am hit by extreme disappointment since the power doesn't work.

I have tried disabling all the userscripts and do a hard refresh, but no dice. The top bar stays black - as black as a moonless night.

By the way, I am using Firefox 28.

Comment: read the unicoins tag wiki

Comment: Well, #thatsthejoke.

Answer (score 9):

It works - open a digital color meter (OS X has one preinstalled, not sure about Windows) and check the color of the bar after making changes. I guarantee it changes*.

<sup>* no guarantees are made about the noticeability of this change with a human retina</sup>

Answer (score 2):

With Undo's help, I finally managed to distinguish the color by slighting adjusting the angle of my laptop screen. Normally, it was slanted a few degree forward, which was enough to cause the change in color *totally* unnoticeable. By adjusting it upright, I managed to see the change in color.

It'd be nice, though, to make the change more prominent.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you purchase a color multimeter - the change is evident and apparent after direct measurement.  We purchased a specialized retina laptop and donated it to Nick Craver in order to confirm the worthiness of this purchase.

Comment: In all seriousness, I think it would be nice to make the color more striking and prominent, like how you did it with the cyan comment and purple posts. Rainbow would even be better.