# Bring back review numbers to the top bar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, flags, top-bar

Though I never quite understood what those numbers were and they were quite ugly, they were **the only reason I ever visited the reviews page**.

[image]
Can we have similar functionality back on the top bar please?

Comment: You're requesting a feature, of something that has been removed that you didn't even understand?

Comment: Why do you want it if you didn't understand it?

Comment: @ben The flag count for mods is to the left of our Gravatar now, along with a diamond which acts as a drop-down for mod messages: http://i.stack.imgur.com/emJ8Q.jpg

Comment: Thanks @animuson. I thought of a better solution anyway... you could just overlay the review link with the number of reviews to be done if you want. 100,289 should cover most of it ;-).

Comment: @animuson But before 10k users were shown the flag count as well; now we're not.

Comment: @Servy Hmmm, that makes sense. Hard to notice that it's missing here on Meta since we don't get a lot of flags that can be seen by 10k users. I imagine they'd add the flag count back in, but to be honest I haven't really cared that the suggested edits count is missing, and I'd rather leave it that way.

Comment: @bluefeet and Cruncher. Because they're the only reason I visit the review page. It's the same reason I update the apps on my phone.. because I want to get rid of the stupid little red number.

Comment: @JamesWebster I've had over 500 unread emails for a year now. I can live with little red numbers :)

Comment: Review 101: the number to the right is amount of pending suggested edits you could review (2K+ rep) and the number to the left is amount of flags you could handle (flag/vote too or disagree with existing flags) in the 10K moderator tools. R.I.P, poor numbers. :)

Comment: @Cruncher Hah. I have 5 emails total. If they're junk or I'm finished with them, they're deleted.

Comment: We are considering this and also some recommendations from the community team. Doesn't seem necessary to rush it. I'm going to let everybody working through next week.

Comment: Related - [notify users of possible reviews on toolbar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar)

Comment: Just to chime in: I know what those indicators are, but I too needed them to remember to do reviews. I would just literally forget that reviews exist if it weren't for the occasional visual cue. I like doing them, but there's just nothing keeping them on my mind.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell The [data](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210133) shows that our concerns were warranted. Suggested edits are now taking a lot longer to be reviewed. Please bring the suggested edit indicator back.

Comment: @Gilles We are still looking at this. Don't want to make a hasty decision. We're going to do something, but I want to make sure that we don't have any better options than rolling back.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell I see it's done, cheers! Any different logic behind the scenes, or is it exactly like it was before?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The number you see back in the top bar is not the suggested edit count; it's the 10k flag count (which we had accidentally forgotten to include when the new top bar rolled out; I hope this is clear when you actually click on it). We're still discussing the best way to handle suggested edit notifications.

Comment: @Laura yep know this, whenever I checked there were less than five suggested edits in the queue so I was hoping they too will appear. Why not next to the flag count, with different color? There's still room for this, except maybe users like Jon Skeet. :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After giving users some time to get used to the top bar and some time to accumulate data about review behavior (hattip to [Gilles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210133/166017)), we've realized that removing the suggested edits indicator was doing more harm than good. It's been added back to the top bar for all users who have access to the suggested edit queue (2k rep).

This is, however, a temporary measure. [We can and should be doing more to get people into *all* review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/211509#211509), not just the suggested edits queue. That becomes a much larger project, however, and I'd like to take a few weeks to work out an intelligent solution to that broader problem. Since suggested edits are already kind of languishing, though, I don't want to make that problem worse while we're scheming about grander things.

**TL;DR:** The suggested edit count will go back in for now, but it may change as part of a broader review notification system sometime after the new year.

**Update:** We now replace the suggested edit count in the top bar with the number of pending reviews for 10k users and diamond moderators. On Stack Overflow, we are currently excluding the Close Vote queue from that, but hopefully we can put it back in once we can control its size a bit better.

Comment: Have a Marauder hat :)

Comment: @JamesWebster I only did it for the hat. :P (Note for posterity: just kidding!)

Comment: Seems like it's enabled for sub 10k users now too (I have 8.5k on [ubuntu.se]). I personally like that, but I suppose it's probably a bug.

Comment: So, will this mean that a consolidated icon for reviews will be added to the top bar ;)?

Comment: @Seth it's not a bug; we decided it made more sense to notify everyone who has access to the queue. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @RolandiXor probably a number, not an icon, but that's the general direction I'm leaning towards. Who knows, though...maybe I'll be able to come up with an icon that intuitively says "review" ;)

Comment: @Laura, could you please give verification that the suggested edit queue starts being accessible at 2k.  I've seen posts that mention 5k and 10k also, and the privileges page only mentions the first and late queues.  Question 2:  Is the limit always 20 posts/day, or does that change with rep?

Comment: @Lance I think [this is good enough proof](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gM8TS.png), regarding review limit it's 20 for all queues except close vote reviews which we have 40 per day due to the huge queue size. It was the same with suggested edits in the past, when there were always 100+ edits to review in the queue, the limit was raised to 40 and reduced back to 20 when things became sane again. Anyway, review limit was never affected by rep. (diamond mods get infinite reviews, by the way :))

Comment: One point is that the suggested edit count is still being displayed when I've hit my review limit. Would be good to only display the counts of anything to do to people who can actually make use of them (similarly for the flags count to people who have used up their flags, etc)

Answer (score 56):

Another reason to bring back the suggested edit indicator is that on smaller sites (i.e. not on SO), the suggested edit indicator is often 0. So a lot of people with the requisite privilege don't keep checking the review queue, they wait for the indicator to appear. Without the indicator, suggested edit reviews will be significantly delayed.

This is not good. Suggested edit review is not like other review tasks which can wait until somebody's interested in doing moderation. A pending suggested edit on a post locks the post against modifications by users without the edit privilege. Without the indicator, posts will spend longer in that semi-locked state.

At least the suggested edit indicator should be immediately visible, at least on sites other than SO.

Here's some data on suggested edit review speed. Methodology: I computed the average time between the submission and the approval or rejection of suggested edits over a 1-week period, or over 100 consecutive suggested edits on the few sites that received more than 100 per week. I measured three 1-week period: the week since the top bar went live (it's been a week today, except on MSO and AU; I excluded AU and took the date of the top bar introduction as a reference on MSO), the week before, and the week before. I chose weeks to avoid effects related to the time of day or day of week, and show two weeks before to get a small idea of the variance. For each period, the table below gives the average delay in minutes (rounded down) and the number of suggested edits that this averages over. The last column expresses the new-top-bar value as a percentage of the old-top-bar value (e.g. 100% means no change, 200% means that reviews take twice as long). I only looked at sites with at least 7.75 questions per day, because slower sites tend not to have a statistically significant sample of suggested edits. (7.75 is where the API throttled me out…) I then filtered out sites where there weren't at least 10 suggested edits during the weeks concerned.

```
                  avg(mn) cnt  avg(mn) cnt  avg(mn) cnt
  site              before^2       before       after
        webmasters      13   35       9   15       5   10    45%
     stackoverflow       6  100       5  100       4   97    74%
                ux      60   12      51   19      42   32    75%
           android      64   16      57   23      52   21    85%
           physics      48   52      40   54      45   54   100%
           webapps     245   26     166   23     229   17   111%
            drupal      72   28      41   30      65   28   115%
            gaming      22   97      28   82      32   88   128%
         wordpress      29   49      20   24      32   37   131%
       mathematica      15   31      35   20      35   34   139%
           magento      68   15      71   16     122   16   175%
         superuser      59  100      65  100     111   99   179%
          security      37   39      58   26      93   51   193%
       electronics      25   52      18   38      46   45   213%
              math       8  100      12  100      22   98   214%
      mathoverflow      18   38      22   28      43   29   214%
             apple      55  100      53   48     123   72   227%
       programmers      30   36      28   30      67   40   229%
               dba     142   16     167   20     382   14   247%
meta.stackoverflow      10   46      12   54      28   59   255%
               tex       4   61       5   52      11   76   256%
               gis      31   47      34   41      84   28   259%
        codereview      36   17      19   17      91   12   328%
             scifi      47   36      57   23     177   29   338%
             stats      13   57      25   31      68   43   358%
              unix      26  100      16  100      78   99   373%
            crypto      29   27      48   15     150    8   389%
           english      24   50      17   43      89   55   424%
        sharepoint      38   23      32   20     158   22   450%
       serverfault      68   80      50   97     292   72   497%
               diy      72   10      26   12     280   13   569%
           bitcoin     129   58     265   46    1319   30   670%
            movies      22   22      37   15     241   11   813%
```

Conclusion: on most sites, there was an increase in the time it took for suggested edits to be reviewed. **On more than half the sites, the time more than doubled.**

The disappearance of the suggested edit indicator is the only change that I can think of to explain this significant increase.

We need it back.

Comment: I would upvote this twice if I could! Exactly what was happening to me since the MetaCollider™ blackout. Took me a while to realize that the non-existence of those numbers didn't mean the non-existence of pending reviews/edits. I'm an active 10k+ (well, 30k+ meanwhile) on Android, and have been watching those numbers regularly ever since I've got the required rep. Miss them very hard! Now I have to check the review queue manually all the time, just to find it empty quite often. This might lead to forgetting about it sooner or later. Not good, as you correctly wrote.

Comment: There are some nice numbers here, but I would like to see two things. 1) Is the measured drop just a temporary effect as people get used to needing to check the review queue when so inclined? 2) Is the _quality_ of reviews better as people chasing ADD-friendly buttons don't see "open for business" signs and the editing gets done by people more familiar with the tools and habits to clean up periodically?

Comment: @bmike Other than SO, what sites have a problem with the quality of suggested edit reviews? Obviously only time can tell whether this is a temporary problem — but it could go both ways: on some sites, I've now taken to checking `/review` more frequently than I used to just to see if there are pending edits, but I don't intend to keep doing this forever.

Comment: I've engaged about one newish user a month on low quality reviews. The stats help and we've not really had to ban anyone yet, but my anecdotal evidence so far is slim as opposed to your great stats. I just wanted to throw the idea out.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your methodology? These results are really interesting to me, and I'm trying to evaluate how big a problem this is and what the best way to solve it is (bringing back the old count, or if we can do something different and better). Specifically, I'm interested in actual date ranges you used (start and end dates for each week) and how you gathered this information. (Where did you pull the reviews and processing time from?)

Comment: @Laura I gave my methodology in my answer. I used the approximate dates of the top bar changeover based on the meta announcements. I retrieved suggested edits from the API. [Here's my script](http://pastebin.com/qJka3ZHG). Feel free to point out if you think I made a mistake.

Answer (score 25):

I'd prefer for the indicator to be shown in the bar - I don't want to have to go dig for it.

Some mockups, in order of what I think looks best first:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `I don't want to have to go dig for it.` - This is important. Out of sight is as bad as not there at all.

Comment: +1 for the middle option. The others just look too "poppy", if that's a word.

Comment: +1 for the first one. Clean and visible.

Comment: +1 for the first two (oops). 1) is clean and not intrusive, 2) makes it easier to not being missed. Cannot decide. But alas, that could even be handled by a UserStyle if one preferes differently. Most important is: bring the numbers back to the MultiCollider™ topbar!

Comment: Nice examples Undo! I just used them in [a userscript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210639/232567) I wrote..

Answer (score 5):

To make it consistent with the other top bar parts, I would just make the "review" change color when there are new suggested edits waiting for review:

> [image]

And tooltip showing how many of those are available.

In ideal world, I would like to see the "review" open into a list of queues, but that's still far away.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to my [**question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210084/233367), I'm sharing my thoughts.
Currently there is only Review option where there is notification like before.  So here is my [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), of *adding dropdown for Review option.*  Which includes the options like
1. 10k Tools
2. Suggested Edits

Here is screenshot of my proposal.

[image]

Comment: While better than nothing, it would still miss the point: catching your eye for needed action. If I have to click the arrow to see if there's "work to do", the same can be achieved by clicking the review-link itself. Still, I see the advantage that it doesn't require a "page switch" but is displayed inline. I prefer to "get noticed I have to click" over to "click to see I have a notice" :)

Comment: @Izzy Yes right :).  But the reason why I prefer `dropdown` menu because all the options in new top bar are `dropdowns` (achievements, inbox, help, profile) and hence to have a common appearance I suggested dropdown.

Comment: I don't think making the review link a drop-down actually accomplishes anything. It's something that I thought of, too, but realized that it's kind of silly...making it a drop down requires a click, but when it's just a link you *already* have the counts for all review queues just one click away. The only difference is a new page load or not, which is a pretty minor concern.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a user script that can put the review count in if you are running Firefox with Greasemonkey extension or Chrome with Tampermonkey:

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/184677