# Getting back the 10K and Review notification

Tags: feature-request, review, 10k-tools, top-bar

Today I saw that new top bar has been implemented in stackoverflow.  But it will fine if we get back the `10K tools` and `Review`.  Currently there is only Review option where there is notification like before.  So here is my [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), of *adding dropdown for Review option.*  Which includes the options like
1. 10k Tools
2. Suggested Edits

Here is screenshot of my proposal.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the second option read "Suggested Edits"? That's what it's indicating... Saying "review" would imply that there's that many things to review over all the queues, no?

Comment: @animuson You're right.  Actually I forget the exact name(thinking for a long time).  Give me few minutes I will correct the screenshot.

Comment: @animuson I have corrected my screenshot.

Comment: I don't miss those. Why were suggested edits singled out in the toolbar out of all queues?

Comment: @Szymon I used to review items using 10K tools every day.  Previously it was easy to navigate, now its not.  Specific reason for "Suggested Edits", because it is the only notified.  Hope you understand.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Though similar question. but I have a proposal here on design.

Comment: It should probably be an answer to the duplicate then @Praveen. Otherwise for every feature request there'd be 20 questions all specifying slightly differing designs.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Ohh, I was not aware of it.  I thought only moderators or 10K users are allowed to answer feature-request.  Shall I leave it or do I need to copy this as an answer to it and close/delete my question?

Comment: @Szymon Because unlike other queues, suggested edits need to be dealt with quickly since they lock the post against further suggested edits.

Comment: @Gilles. That makes sense, didn't think about it.

Comment: If you think it adds something @PraveenJeganathan then post an answer by all means! There's no need to delete this. Duplicates can be useful to point everyone to the one question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd prefer for the indicator to be shown in the bar - I don't want to have to go dig for it.

Some mockups, in order of what I think looks best first:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second one is very nice.