# 10 K Moderator tools and new toolbar

Tags: discussion, feature-request, 10k-tools, top-bar

From today onwards StackOVerflow is having the new toolbar. I have a question about it.

In Old toolbar it shows the 10K Moderator Tools (Remaining Flagged post count, Remaining suggested edit count etc).

[image: Old Toolbar]

But in new toolbar it's not present:

[image: New Toolbar]

Where is those moderator tools ? Where can I get those in new tool bar ?

Comment: As of now, you can't via the toolbar. You could either click review, and then click tools.. or just use the direct link.. http://stackoverflow.com/tools OR.. [use a userscript](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210010/232567). I'm using Travis's, but I tweaked it to add this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PcG0V.png

Comment: I too have a proposal here http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210084/233367

Comment: @JoshC: Thanks for the comment and userscripts :)