# Conditionally show and hide the review button

Tags: feature-request, review, top-bar

I would like to request two changes related to the `review` button in the top-bar:

1. It should show only when there're reviews pending, and might show the number of reviews, like it did in the old design. (Remember that while there're lots and lots of reviews pending on SO, on most of the other sites you get a review once in hour or less).
2. Make a review button next to `chat` and `blog` in the SE logo drop menu, so that the review statistics and history are accessible nevertheless.

There are two reasons for this request:

- You don't really need `review` button when there's nothing to review.
- Once there is something to review, you want it to be more noticable, which is when you suddenly show the button.

Comment: The review history and the review badge progress are both accessed through the `review` link. It does not make sense to hide it.

Comment: @episanty It makes sense to hide it, since as I said, it's useless most of the time on most of the sites. I can't speak for others really, but I know that lots of people use it only to perform reviews, not to review reviews. And to get to the review history and stats, you would have the new button in the logo drop menu, as I suggested.

Comment: I could see highlighting the review in some way possibly (disabled on SO since it would always be lit), but that may be too busy as well - passing it along.

Comment: @NickCraver It's interesting that in the old design, it was like that: There appeared a number of reviews pending next to the `review` button. And no-one complained. So I don't see why it should be a problem.

Comment: @tohecz ***Many*** people complained about the old bar changing all the time.  And trust me when I say "no-one complained", no matter what you're talking about here, will ever be accurate.  The count or an indicator may in fact make a some re-appearance, but we're letting things settle before making any changes.

Comment: Which means that we'll have this whole stupid and uncomfortable thing for a long time before any official change. Fancy people (probably hundreds-to-thousands of them) will make their jQ or whatever modifications, only to be angry again when the top bar changes, once it's "settled down". Do you see how misfortunate this is?

Comment: @episanty This question has nothing to do with review history or badges.

Comment: The “number of reviews” was actually the number of pending suggested edits (with a reputation theshold that varied over time). There's a [separate request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209998/bring-back-review-numbers-to-the-top-bar) to bring it back.