# Could I opt out of the notification for http://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, top-bar

Of late, my eye is burned by the bright orange reminder of content in https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged.

I've long ago given up on that URL. The interaction model in there, for me, is nearly always,

1. look at an item
2. decide that I need full context to decide
3. click through to deal
4. discover that I now can't dismiss it from the page, because I had to use the limited-context buttons for the page to realize that I've acted.

Right now, meta presents me with a '1' in a red box for a question that I have already voted to close.

Further, much of the content here is 'close flags'. If I wanted to get depressed about the close backlog, I'd visit the main close review queue, I don't need these to help.

So, I'd like some way to get rid of the burning orange box so that I can go back to ignoring this.

On the other hand, I'd be really happy to see a notification that there is work for me in the review queues (other than close -- obviously, if you included that, the answer is always yes.) Just a simple bat-signal, no numbers.

Comment: Since this is a [work in progress](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212225/171964), now is definitely the right time to ask for features like this.