# Review numbers in the top bar on the right

Tags: discussion, support, review

I have just noticed it this morning that there is a new number available between the bronze edge number and the review word in the top bar on the right, just on the left on the search field.

Is this a recent addition because I have not seen it like that before? It is coming up in an orange color, and perhaps it is related to the reviews in some sense? I cannot be sure because when I have two suggested edits available for review, I am not getting it. I saw this number being 5 the few times it came up.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: It's only ever been shown when there are at least 5 suggested edits on SO... If you have 2 in the queue that's not enough to trigger it.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: ah, right. That makes sense.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: do you know how often it is refreshed? For instance, it stays around for a while like 5 even when there is no more suggested edits in the queue, or at least not 5 anymore.

Answer (score 5):

[image: topbar]

The left one is the flag queue size and the right one the suggest edits queue size *.

<sub>* The queue size numer is cached and may not be acccurate all the time. Also when the queue is empty, no number will be displayed in the top-bar.</sub>

Comment: Interesting because as I wrote in the question, I do not see "2" in there right now when I have 2 suggested edits in the queue. Perhaps, it is unfortunately capturing now the state when it is zero in a certain time interval?

Comment: It is cached. Currently I see only the flag queue size.

Comment: It too don't see suggested edits flags like that near 10k flag.

Comment: That is because there are no suggested edits right now

Comment: Many thanks. +1'd the answer. Can you update the answer with this cache information?

Comment: @juergend related http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/why-new-orange-notification-icon

Comment: @juergend notifications but without queue looks annoying, instead if that notification disappear when there is no queue then its fine.

Comment: Do you know if it is meant to stay around after the winter hat session as well, or it is now like that to help people collecting the hats? :-) I personally did not feel the need for such a feature like this because luckily enough, we have many useful contributors keeping the review edit queue close to zero most of the time.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I am confident that it will stay like this.

Comment: @LaszloPapp This is unrelated to hats. The suggested edit indicator used to be shown to users with 10k rep (and before that to users with 5k rep). It was briefly removed when the [new top bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207420) was brought in, then [reintroduced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212225) because [suggested edits were languishing due to a lack of attention](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210133), now shown to everyone with 2k rep.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan On SO (and I think on SO only), due to the review velocity, the suggested edit indicator is only shown when the value is ≥5.

Comment: @Gilles you're right.  I'm able to see now, thanks.