# Suggested Edits review queue notification after maximum limit reached

Tags: discussion, support, review, suggested-edits

Having got a bit more information about the suggested edits notification [in my previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213041/review-numbers-in-the-top-bar-on-the-right), I think I have one more question here.

As you can see on my edited screenshot below, I am getting the notifications even though I am not available to contribute more to it because I exceeded the daily quota. I would need to come back later to help with this further on.

This brings to my questions: am I thinking something wrong or perhaps it would be better to pause the operation of the notifications for the person when it is not possible to help more on the given day, and refresh it when the day expires.

Currently, it does not seem to be such information that I would use for something. If I wish, I could still see this notification when I visit the review tab. It may be possible that I lack some context.

Apparently, there is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes) thread, but it is talking about 10k, and I do not even have 5k reputation. Is this related to that the limit was changed?

So, is this intentional for the future? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I edited that other feature-request with current information and voted-to-close this as a dupe of that.