# Please remove the top bar indicator after completing review limit

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, top-bar

It's glad to see the [top bar indicator for review suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212225/186599).

But, the top bar still indicating the items count to be reviewed after completing daily limit(20 for suggested edit).

I requested not to show the review indicator after limit reached.

Comment: Or at least make it faded, so we know something is there, but we can't do a thing about that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I think it's not a dupe, that question is discussing about moderation tools(10k suggested edit review counter). But, here it's about the new feature available for 2k users.

Comment: @Azik no, it's a dupe. The number was always displayed for 2K users and it's not part of the 10K tools.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, but I saw this feature recently(this week only).

Comment: @Azik because the new top bar did not have it. In the old top bar, didn't you see the suggested edits indicator?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, No, I didn't see the indicator in the old topbar.

Comment: @Azik I see. Still, it is the same request exactly it doesn't really matter that now more users see that number.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Anyway I closed it :)