# Do posts closed/deleted as offensive automatically get flagged to mods?

Tags: support, flags, moderation, offensive

Do posts that are removed via "offensive" flags also end up being seen by moderators?

I realize the flags end up in a moderator queue, but once the content is deleted (thanks to a sufficient number of users flagging), do they remain?

It's just, occasionally people post content that is **so** inappropriate and/or abusive that simple removal seems inadequate and action on the account may be necessary; would be good to know a mod sees them and can take further steps if warranted.

These excellent posts ([ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work?rq=1), [ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work?rq=1)) describe the flags and what happens with them, but don't say whether a mod will still see the content once the threshold has been passed:

[This answer on another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102366/134069) implies that a moderator *won't* see them because they're deemed "dealt with."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do posts that are removed via "offensive" flags also end up being seen by moderators?

No. There is no system in place to notify moderators of these posts or users, if the flags are handled by the community. Once the offensive flags are processed, it leaves our queue and we've got no record of it.

However, if there are additional flags on the post, like a custom "other" flag then that will hang around even though the post is deleted. Those are the only flags that aren't automatically cleared when a post is deleted.

Comment: Thanks. That confirms the implication in [Anna's answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102366/134069). Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. As far as I can tell (not a mod myself, just from what I see around) those flags just sit in the moderator queue like all other flags.

There is a  pending feature request to give a better alert: [Can we get a visual indication that there are spam or offensive posts in the flag queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216235/can-we-get-a-visual-indication-that-there-are-spam-or-offensive-posts-in-the-fla)

Anyway, when the post is deleted the flags are removed from the queue. That's the reason we can see many spam account still "alive" long after posting the spam.