# Notification for reviews shows way too many

Tags: support, status-completed, review, notifications, top-bar

Since a [recent change in notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212225/225745), I see more than I should:

[image: screenshot]

I see no reason to see 134 posts are awaiting review, when there is literally nothing I can do about them. I think it is a bug, because notification is meant as something that will make me act. When I know I usually can't, obviously I will start to ignore it.

If it's not a bug, please remove bug tag and explain how it is supposed to be useful, or how can I switch to only seeing notifications about things I can act on.

Note that apaprently there are no flags for me, neither. I see only *stats*, *migrated*, *close*, *delete*, there, as if there was no flags waiting:

[image: Screenshot for prev paragraph]

## If you expect us to click on it every few minutes

just to see personalized numbers next to queues, why don't you simply query for personalized numbers every few minutes and cache them for us? It should cost you similar, in database usage, and will save us a lot of clicking and frustration.

## If all this number means is "there might be reviews, or not" or "for sure there are none"

it would be simpler just to hide "review" link in the second case. We don't need two links with the same function next to each other, thank you, one is enough, and meaningless numbers are only irritating.

Comment: Same on Cognitive Sciences right now. I see [some oddness on DBA](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/1112) too, as mentioned in the comment on the question @Jehof linked. Anna Lear responded, "Not bugged. The topbar count is every review in the system, not just the ones available to you (ie ones you haven't skipped or already otherwise acted on)." Shog9 says, "this is everything in review, even stuff that you, personally, can't review. Super-expensive to personalize this - so the alternative is simply not having an indicator. Think of it as... A reminder to encourage your peers to review."

Comment: @Molot. Yeah for me too on Stackoverflow. Now i´m more confused. Currently I think the number displays to much information

Comment: @NickStauner If it "works as designed", then I think it is a design bug that will make people ignore this count.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how this change completes that feature request, as it seems to ignore the last two sentences of that question: "**This should be something that you can get to 0 every day**. Making it something that is an unmanageable number makes it something people will ignore, and that's not what this is suggesting." I sure hope this doesn't become a ever-present notification I have to learn to just ignore...

Comment: The implementation is not 'personalised' and is also cached. This isn't a design bug; it is a limitation of what a site at Stack Overflow scale can achieve with such a number.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It can show me personified number on each queue separately all right, but suddenly **adding six or ten integers is over it's limitation**? Sorry, can't believe it.

Comment: For the top bar shown on each and every page? Yes.

Comment: Specifically, see [Anna Lear's response](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726): *It doesn't take individual user actions into account at all at the moment* and *It is also cached, so may or may not be very accurate depending on the amount of ongoing activity in /review at any given time.*

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's what cache is for, isn't it? If they expect me to click notifications to get *my* numbers every few minutes, why can't they automatically refresh cache to get me these numbers without a click, the same few minutes? And if they expect me to only click when I feel like reviewing, no matter any numbers, then I already have a link for that, I don't need another.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'd say it is the other way around - if it is a network-wide, it should be resolved here, not there.

Comment: @Mołot actually it should be in both places. When trying to flag network related things in MSO asking to migrate to MSE, my flags were rejected. (For the record, I didn't see this report here before submitting my own, assuming it's SO only issue)

Comment: This is a network-wide bug, as I'd come here to report the same thing regarding what I see on ServerFault.

Comment: I'm re-opening this because, although it is a direct consequence of [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar), the concerns are specific and distinct from those expressed or addressed there. This behavior is absolutely *not* an accident; rather, it is an intentional trade-off for which in return we get the ability to call attention to what on many sites is an often-ignored but incredibly powerful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed [as of October 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly): pending task counts are no longer shown outside of /review to anyone.