# Notification of quantity of reviews needed in review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, top-bar

On big sites such as SO, there is always something in the review queue. This is not the case in smaller sites. Often times I will forget to check whether something is in the queue, and miss an opportunity to work on my Reviewer badge.

To solve this issue, you could add a counter showing how many things are awaiting review as such.

[image]

Comment: Possessive reviews or multiple reviews?

Comment: @random What???? never heard of those, I was just thinking normal reviews.

Comment: @random As a possessive reviewer, I approve of that apostrophe.

Comment: @random now I see, Ooops!

Comment: They already have this, don't they?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar which prompted the complaint that it's too noisy  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-much?lq=1 (but I think it's still there?)  You just need to have access to the 10k privileges (or 2K on beta sites).

Comment: Unless you want this for all potential reviewers, but see [Laura's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211509/160551) for why it's not that way.