# A way to see which review queue has remaining tasks when there's no personally actionable items

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools, 10k-tools

The number of pending review tasks shown in the top bar for 10k users and moderators is decoupled from the number of actionable items you see on the list of review queues. The brown number in the top bar could be non-zero, while the number next to each review queue showing flat zeroes, indicating that there's no actionable items for you<sup>1</sup>.

The reason behind this is explained in [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-much).

The number in the top bar is meant ["to give you a high-level overview of what's happening on your site"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5763) and ["if that number is getting bigger in spite of everything you do... Then it's time to raise a call for action."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230802/157841)

As a moderator for a private beta site targeted at an audience fairly new to the SE platform, I'd like to "raise a call for action" to clear up this modest number of pending tasks, which has been sitting at this count for several days:

[image: sitting at 7]

To do that, I'd like to be able to give specific directions for people on where to look at and what to do: "such-and-such queue has X remaining tasks: here is how to review things in that list."

At the moment, I cannot see which queue is blocked up. It'd be helpful to either

- Let 10k users and/or moderators see the actual pending review tasks
- Let 10k users and/or moderators see the number of globally pending review tasks *per queue*

---

<sup>1</sup>This is not about when you've used up the daily review quota. There's no actionable items because you've truly processed all items. However, you've skipped some items along the way and that's why the top bar indicator shows there're some review tasks left for the community to process.

Comment: One way is to open the site in a private browsers window, you don't need to be logged in to see numbers on /review.

Comment: @PeterJ It worked! I had to fiddle with a cookie because my site is in private beta though.