# Can we briefly explain the "wrong" review count where new reviewers will see it?

Tags: feature-request, review, help-center-proposed

A frequently-asked question across the network is why the number in the top bar next to the "review" link doesn't match the tally of items visible in the queues.  It seems like this has come up on every site where I'm active, and it's come up a lot here on MSE.  Some of those roads lead to [this explanation of this design decision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742/162102); check out some of the linked questions there for just a taste of the MSE repetition:

[image: related questions]

Documenting it better won't stop all the questions because we can't assume that people read documentation.  But [it might help some people](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/whatbisnthe-number-next-to-the-review-link#comment4468_2003) and we sure can't assume that new reviewers on other sites will find their way to MSE on their own.  (Especially betas, where that kicks in at 350 rep.)

Could we add a sentence or two about this somewhere where new reviewers might see it?  Perhaps directly on the review page (h/t Shog9), or in the Help Center on the "access review queues" privilege description?

Comment: Probably makes more sense to put it right on the review page in this scenario.

Comment: @Shog9 oh that's a good point.  A line or two up top wouldn't harm that page.

Comment: I would add a link in the right sidebar, below "Choose a task on the left to get started",