# Colossal formatting bug on profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, spelling, tooltips

While taking refuge from the [storm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209957/is-anyone-else-personally-terrified-of-the-new-bar-at-the-top), I ended up on my profile page, whereupon I came across the most awful bug.

[image]

[image]

There should be [at least one](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2544) space in there!

Comment: Colossal is a bit of an over statement don't you think? Its just a missing space.

Comment: +1 for a proportional response

Comment: @apaul34208 sarcasm isn't a thing anymore, is it?

Comment: I am certain this is a dupe.

Comment: @Oded How could you have not got around to fixing something so major in over a year?

Comment: @fredley A year? It's only been 2 months as far as I can see.

Comment: @Stijn Whoops, read it as Oct '12 for some reason.

Comment: @Stijn if this issue can be called colossal, then the elapsed time can be called an epoch just as well ;)