# StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ inbox & New Top bar collisions on chat homepage & API

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, global-inbox, top-bar

The [new top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209957/is-anyone-else-personally-terrified-of-the-new-bar-at-the-top#210338) is live everywhere, but the [chat homepage](https://chat.stackexchange.com/), which still shows the old design and the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ inbox.

Also, it seems like clicking on the new Recent inbox messages doesn't clear the old StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ inbox content, so I'm left with this:

[image]

[image]

Because of this [Stack Alert](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bpficcollblmkmoofnbnfhibdhfolamm) tells me there are messages in the inbox, when I've cleared it.

Can this be looked into please?

Comment: Note: Stack Alert pulls its information from the API, so that would need to be corrected in order to solve your problem.